# Split and Validate Comparison Expression in java

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I am building a Rest service. My service Resource method is like this :

```
public Response<List<AuditEvent>> getAuditEvents(@QueryParam("filters") List<AuditRequest.Filter> filters,
                                                 @QueryParam("orderBy") @DefaultValue("id") String order,
                                                 @QueryParam("isDesc") @DefaultValue("true") boolean desc,
                                                 @QueryParam("startTime") long startTimestamp,
                                                 @QueryParam("endTime") long endTimestamp,
                                                 @QueryParam("limit") @DefaultValue("20") int size,
                                                 @QueryParam("offset") @DefaultValue("0") int startIndex)
```

Here filters can be multiple expression like :

```
/api/audit/query/?filters=username='admin'&filters=customerId=1&limit=1&orderBy=rowId&isDesc=false&offset=2
```

I have made a Filter class also :

```
public static class Filter {
    private String propertyId;
    private String op;
    private Object value;
```

}

Please suggest me a good approach to convert `List<String>` that am getting in Resource method to `List<Filters>` and also validating each String expression is valid or not. Basically, I need a   parser to convert this string expression to my Filter Object where operator can be any valid operator.

Answer (score 2):

I think your query is not clear and lean.

Please consider:

https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser

A few examples:

- name=="Kill Bill";year=gt=2003
- name=="Kill Bill" and year>2003
- genres=in=(sci-fi,action);(director=='Christopher Nolan',actor==*Bale);year=ge=2000
- genres=in=(sci-fi,action) and (director=='Christopher Nolan' or actor==*Bale) and year>=2000
- director.lastName==Nolan;year=ge=2000;year=lt=2010

If you want to write your own solution, please consider matrix variables:
filters=name=abc;age>40;....

Hope it work.

Comment: i don't said it's wrong. it's only not clear and lean so much (too many filters param here)

Comment: ok got your point...but what is the other way if I want to take it as a list in queryparam . Because  if i use this way filters=name=abc;age>40;  i have to convert to list by separator.